# "Will rotate" notification?

Tags: ios, notifications, screen-rotation

Is it possible to get a "will rotate" notification on iOS, **before** the rotation animations are executed? Like the `UIViewController` method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.

I know of `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, but that one appears to be sent **after** the rotation animations are executed.

I'm working in a `NSObject` subclass, outside of view controllers.

If there is no such notification, I was considering a hack such as adding a "fake" view to the view hierarchy (to the `rootViewController`'s view?), and override `layoutSubviews` to send a custom notification. Is there a less hackish alternative?

Comment: You mean like the UIViewController method willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:?

Comment: Ok, I'll bite... If you're not working in UI related code, why do you need to be notified of a pending rotation event? Relaying these event messages is typically the job of a ViewController.

Comment: @RicPerrott I'm working in UI related code outside of a `UIViewController`. I'm dealing with a legacy controller class of a custom `inputAccesoryView`, which works independently of my view controllers. It might be possible to refactor it into a `UIViewController` subclass, but that's a topic for another question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UIApplicationDelegate Protocol `application:willChangeStatusBarOrientation:duration:`

You can use one of these two methods to see:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation;
```

Apple's UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: At least as far as the delegate method didChangeStatusBarOrientation is concerned, this is called by iOS well before the rotation is actually completed. Which seems quite odd to me. I'm testing this on an iPad on iOS8.4. Overriding the view controller method didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation provides much more satisfactory timing for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, if you check in the method that you have registered for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, the DEVICE orientation([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) is the new device orientation after rotation, but the INTERFACE orientation (self.interfaceOrientation) is still the older one. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` has the new interface orientation.